# Using custom angular directive into kendo ui grid as column template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I have created a custom angular directive, number control, and would like to use that in kendo ui grid column template.

How to achieve this? Could someone provide an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

suppose your directive name is myDirective. You can apply template as

```
template: '<my-directive></my-directive>'
```

or

```
template: '<span my-directive></span>'
```